# Place a caption on the border of images

Tags: html, css, border, image-gallery

Well I want to place a caption on the border of my images for a image gallery I am developing.
Basically my images use borders and margins to create a effect around them to make them look like Polaroid photos. I would like to place a caption on top of the border. here is my css.

```
.column img {
    position:relative; 
    display:inline-block; 
    width:130px; 
    height:100px;
    margin: auto; 
    padding:10px; 
    background:#fff; 
    box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    box-shadow: 1px 3px  3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 5px 5px 35px 5px;
}

.column div {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 5px 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The border works fine and looks fine but the caption does not display on top of the border any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Might help if you supplied the HTML so we could reproduce and help diagnose

Comment: Provide your HTML semantic too.!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the <fieldset> and <legend> tags to draw a captioned box around the images. 

`<fieldset>

<legend>Caption Here</legend>

<!-- Image here -->

</fieldset>`